Override response code in spring data rest generated api
We use spring data rest annotating repositories with @RepositoryRestResource which provides CRUD APIs by default. In spring boot 2.7.3 which we currently use, delete API returns

204 no content

But in spring boot 3.1.8 upgrade, delete API response code changed to 200 OK. This is causing issues as the associated entities were not available after the session was closed but Spring trying to return a GET 200 OK response.
I am looking for documentation on why this changed as 204 has been the default response code for delete and a solution to override the response code to 200 for any delete requests

Ok found it here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/reference/repository-resources.html#repository-resources.item-resource.supported-methods.delete

It would be nice if you could provide an answer with details as to why and how it solves your issue.

As per the documentation here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/reference/repository-resources.html#repository-resources.item-resource.supported-methods.delete
Spring returns 200 OK with body if the request contains Accept header. We can make it return 204 No Content by setting setReturnBodyOnDelete on RepositoryRestConfigurer
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
        config.setReturnBodyOnDelete(false);
    }
} 

